# Strange Javascript behavior on some Android web where event triggered twice for specific value, how to workaround this?

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I encounter strange bugs that might be related with some Android issue since this issue was reproduced on 1 of my phone. Tried other 10 phones and emulators and the issue was not reproduced. Desktop browser also seems to be fine.

The source code is something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <main>
            <span>
                Amount
            </span>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="amt" id="amt" value="" maxlength="11" class="form-control cc-fs-6" placeholder="Put 1000 to 1009">
            </div>
            <div id="inputDiv">
            </div>
            </main>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                amt = document.getElementById('amt')
                // amt.addEventListener("keyup", updateValue);
                amt.addEventListener("input", updateValue);
                
                function updateValue() {
                    amount = document.getElementById('amt').value;

                    inputDiv = document.getElementById('inputDiv');
                    inputDiv.innerHTML += "Amt1: " + document.getElementById('amt').value + "<br>";
                    amount = amount.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    // using regex:
                    // format = amount.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.'); 
                    
                    // using plain
                    var format = "";
                    var n = amount.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        format += amount.charAt(i);
                        if ((n - i - 1) % 3 === 0 && i !== n - 1) {
                          format += ".";
                        }
                    }
                    
                    inputDiv.innerHTML += "Amt2: " + document.getElementById('amt').value + "<br>";
                    document.getElementById('amt').value = format;
                    inputDiv.innerHTML += "Amt3: " + document.getElementById('amt').value + "<br>";
                };
            </script><!-- Bottom Nav Bar -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The purpose in the code above is only to format to have thousand separator when user press a number.
However, when user put number 1000 to 1009, the key up event is triggered twice on the phone. And the 2nd event read different value. If I put 1000, it will give 10001000.
I tried different browser such as Chrome, Firefox and original web browser, and it happens on all of those.

Currently, what I do right now is skipping the script when user put 1000 to 1009. I have tried preventDefault and stopPropagation but it doesn't give any difference. What makes it stranger is, on the second trigger, the value sent is difference from what I set (see screenshot). But, If I set the same amount, the event still triggered twice, but the value didn't change.
Anybody encounter the same issue, and any idea how to workaround this or explain what is really happening?

5 customers has report this behavior to me, so I can't ignore it. Btw, my phone is POCO F4, if it might help.

[image: Save the source code above and send it over WA, open it using browser. This happens.]

```js
amt = document.getElementById('amt')
amt.addEventListener("input", updateValue);

function updateValue() {
  amount = document.getElementById('amt').value;

  inputDiv = document.getElementById('inputDiv');
  inputDiv.innerHTML += "Amt1: " + document.getElementById('amt').value + "<br>";
  amount = amount.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

  var format = "";
  var n = amount.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    format += amount.charAt(i);
    if ((n - i - 1) % 3 === 0 && i !== n - 1) {
      format += ".";
    }
  }

  inputDiv.innerHTML += "Amt2: " + document.getElementById('amt').value + "<br>";
  document.getElementById('amt').value = format;
  inputDiv.innerHTML += "Amt3: " + document.getElementById('amt').value + "<br>";
};
```

```html
<main>
  <span>
                Amount
            </span>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="amt" id="amt" value="" maxlength="11" class="form-control cc-fs-6" placeholder="Put 1000 to 1009">
  </div>
  <div id="inputDiv">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: `keydown` and `keyup` are unreliable on mobile devices, you should use `input` event instead

Comment: A double `keyup` event doesn't explain this behavior, given the code you have to process the event. I suspect the problem lies in [the processing of the regular expression](https://chuniversiteit.nl/papers/regular-expression-bugs). I would try a simpler solution, without the regular expression.

Comment: No, it is really a key up. Even without regex, it still fire the event twice.

Comment: Update after using input: Unfortunately, it still gives duplicate events. Maybe, I can try change the question so it didn;t use regex.

Comment: I still don't see, given the code, how the output would double, just because the event fires twice. Still, it's not a bad idea to change `keyup` to `input`. I've created an alternative for your second RegExp: `format = amount.substr(0, amount.length - 3) + '.' + amount.substr(-3);`. You could try it.

Comment: yeah, I know it strange. I have change it to input and change the source code on the question as well and the screenshot so we can all see the strangenes. Remember, this is not happening on all environment. And, if I put 2000, it formatted correctly.

Comment: Btw, I don't think there is something wrong with the code. My question is more on the correct "workaround".

Comment: Yes, I also don't think it's the code, and it's clearly also not the regular expression. It is noticeable that it happens when you actually increase the length of the content of the input field for the first time, by adding the dot. There might be a problem with that? Remember the input field still has the focus of the keyboard. I'm not sure what the best "workaround" for this would be.

Comment: OK, to test whether it is the dot you could try this: Instead of inserting a dot you could change one of the digits. So instead of changing `1000` to `1.000` you could change it to `%000`. That way you'll know whether changing the length of the string matters.

Comment: If I put 1000 to 4000, it will change to 40001000 on the Amt1. If I use non numeric, the number will stuck in the first replace regex.

Comment: I don't think you understand my point. I didn't mean you should input non-numeric characters. In your code you do: `format += ".";`, which makes the string you put back in the input field one character longer. This might upset the browser since it thinks it has 4 characters. So I asked to not add the dot, but instead change one of the digits.

Comment: I do. The one that I posted in the comment above is what happens. Instead of adding "." I change number to "4". So, 1000 becoming 4000. And the second fire event sending 40001000 as a result (without comma or anything else). Really strange isn't it ?

Comment: Very strange indeed. I ran out of ideas. Why would the fourth digit be special? What if you don't insert of dot or change a digit? Does it then still double after the fourth digit? Does it always double when you change anything? I cannot test these things, but you can.

Comment: what's special is not the 4 digit but 1000 to 1009. If I put 1010, 2000, or 9999, it runs correctly.

Comment: @Kosmas facing similar issue, did you manage to fix this yet?

Comment: not yet. If I found the answer I will post it here. But right now I decide to disable autoformatting for that specific value. But, if in some case it triggers other things, I don't know what to do.